# How do I change iOS7 status bar text to white in Titanium Alloy?

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, ios7-statusbar

I've just created a new Mobile Web App in Titanium Studio and added this to the tiapp.xml file:

```
<ios>
    <plist>
        <dict>
            <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
            <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
        </dict>
    </plist>
</ios>
```

But the ios7 status bar doesn't change in the iPhone simulator.  The text is black when the default image (splash screen) is in view and the hello world window has a 20px black bar at the top with nothing in it (presumably black text on black background).

What am I doing wrong?  Why doesn't the above XML change the status bar text to white?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you do not need to write the tags in tiapp.xml

Just give `statusBarStyle` property to window like

```
var baseWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'black',
    statusBarStyle : Ti.UI.iPhone.StatusBar.LIGHT_CONTENT        
});
```

for alloy try

```
<Window id="win" title="Win 1" backgroundColor='#F0FFFF' statusBarStyle=Ti.UI.iPhone.StatusBar.LIGHT_CONTENT>
```

for more just read the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iPhone.StatusBar-property-LIGHT_CONTENT)

[image]